# How to make shrunken textures look pretty

Tags: opengl, c++, 2d

I am drawing lots of textures and panning and zooming in and out on them. When the camera zooms out they look really ugly.

What can I do?

Comment: Did you try generating mipmaps?

Comment: Might also help to provide some screenshots of what exactly you're talking about.  Could be a couple things, but as bummzack said, probably mipmaps.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/pdzdS theres zoomed in and zoomed out

Comment: That texture is a bad example, no matter what, its tiled, it will always look strange zoomed out (esp since it has a distinct pattern)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup, looks like mipmaps.  [This looks like it might be a good resource](http://www.swiftless.com/tutorials/opengl/mipmap_generation.html) on how to add them in.  Once in though, you can manipulate the filtering - try enabling [trilinear filtering](http://gregs-blog.com/2008/01/17/opengl-texture-filter-parameters-explained/) or [anisotropic filtering](http://steinsoft.net/index.php?site=Programming/Code%20Snippets/OpenGL/anisotropicfiltering).

Comment: gluBuild2DMipmaps is a bad function to suggest. If you are targeting OpenGL 2, you should use GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP. If you are targeting OpenGL 3, you should use glGenerateMipmaps.

Comment: Also, for preference, don't even bother with online generation. You can generate mips offline pretty easily, which only adds around 30% to your texture sizes, but saves a ton of loading time. You can also experiment with alternate shrinking filters to achieve the look you want (sharper, softer, etc). As for filtering: if you're only doing 2D screens, don't bother with anything but linear: anisotropic filtering is for coping with changing mip levels across a single polygon, which can't happen if you're orthogonal to the camera.

Comment: Online generation is still useful if you're doing dynamic textures. Some 2D APIs I have worked with will automatically atlas as you load (under the premise a 2D game is more likely to load lots of small textures, and the artist burden of manually atlasing would be large), which requires online mipmap generation.

Comment: Made my answer a community wiki - haven't done openGl in years so others can suggest better resources in the answer if they want.